# How to add data in Firebase Database with unique keys and then fetch the data with unique keys?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

-LUeq8x-5QaVSXKJdXtz is the key
[image: -LUeq8x-5QaVSXKJdXtz is the key]

```
signup = async () => {
    const { email, pass, job, description, name, age } = this.state;
// fetching state variables to use in this function


    try {   
      await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass);

      var playersRef = firebase.database().ref("doctorsList/");

//push function adds the data with a unique key
      playersRef.push({
        doctor: {
          name: name,
          age: age,
          job: job,
          description: description
      },
      });
}
catch (error) { console.log(error)  }
}
```

How do I fetch the data from Firebase database if they have unique keys?

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref( 'doctorsList/doctor/' );

  ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    alert(snapshot.val().name);
 });
```

When I use `alert(snapshot.val().name);` it shows me the name from the database but when I try to save data by `this.setState({ name: snapshot.val().name });` it doesn't saves. Or how can I save the data at once from database?

Answer (score 2):

Tony's answer shows how to get the doctor once you know their key. There are also various scenarios where you may not know the key.

For example, if you know nothing about the doctor you want to read, all you can do is read the information for all doctors:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref( 'doctorsList' );

ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doctorSnapshot) => {
    alert(doctorSnapshot.key+": "+doctorSnapshot.val().doctor.name);
  });
});
```

If you know for example the name of the doctor(s), you can use a query to retrieve the doctor(s) matching that name with:

```
ref.orderByChild("doctor/name").equalTo("shubham").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doctorSnapshot) => {
    alert(doctorSnapshot.key);
  });
});
```

You'll still need `snapshot.forEach` here, since there may be multiple doctors with a matching name.

If you'd like to change something about each of those doctors, you can update it within the callback with:

```
ref.orderByChild("doctor/name").equalTo("shubham").on('value', (snapshot) => {
  snapshot.forEach((doctorSnapshot) => {
    doctorSnapshot.ref.child("job").set("doctor");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Frank. But I'm unable to save value get by snapshot.val().name in a state variable. For eg: I'm unable to save it by this.setState({ name: snapshot.val() });

Comment: What does "I'm unable" mean here? Is there an error message? Doesn't it get rendered? Please be concise and precise.

Comment: I'm doing this  --                                                                                       
   this.setState({ name: snapshot.val().name })   // this doesn't updates the name. I want to save the data fetched from database
But if I just use ----  alert(snapshot.val().name);    // this shows me the name

Comment: please help! I'm confused how to save data fetched from firebase database

Comment: How are you using the data that you set in the state? The code you shared doesn't show that, making it hard to help further than what Tony and I have already done. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to learn how to create a standalone reproduction of the problem, which in turn makes it much more likely we can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upload with the specific key, change the ref to this:

```
const key = //your key here;
var playersRef = firebase.database().ref(`doctorsList/${key}`);
```

And then if you want to fetch the data with a specific key, change to this:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref( `doctorsList/${key}`);

  ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    alert(snapshot.val().name);
 });
```